# drawing a map of the Bronx - d3.geo.path()

Tags: d3.js

Trying to take GIS data of the 
zip codes of the Bronx and turn it into a map using d3.js.  But I am having trouble rendering.  Could you show me proper use of `d3.geo.path()` ?

```
<script>
    var width=960, height=500;
    var path = d3.geo.path();
    d3.json("/static/bxzip.json", function(d){
        d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
        .data(d.data)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d",function(d) { return d[9][5].rings[0]; })
        .attr("class", "stroke");
    });
</script>
```

Here is a typical line of `d[9][5].rings[0]` from https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Social-Services/Bronx-Zip-Code-Boundaries/p8wz-d63u

```
[ [ -73.84463693999993, 40.90475939500004 ], [ -73.84443733899991, 40.90423928800004 ], [ -73.84443555299993, 40.904234630000076 ],  ...] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your array into path() to get it to return screen xy:

```
.attr("d",function(d) { return path(d[9][5].rings[0]); })
```